# How can I hook up multiple RFID readers to communicate to a Raspberry Pi wirelessly?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid, xbee

I've done some research and found out about `XBees`. Can I use this with `RFID` readers? I am planning to use `RC522 RFID` reader as its the cheapest option for me at the moment.

I am open to any advice or suggestion for other methods to achieve my objective. Thanks!

Comment: Please try and improve your question, else it is likely to get closed for being too broad or unclear. What are you actually trying to do? How/why do you think XBees are related to RFID readers?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is send the data from the reader to the Raspberry Pi wirelessly since both will be apart for quite a distance. Xbees can transmit data from a device to another, wirelessly based from what I learned.

Comment: Given that your question is more about hardware interoperability, and that StackOverflow is more about programming, I think you'd be better off asking on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com and also get a better answer there.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XBee with any device that has a TTL level serial interface.  The simplest configuration of paired XBee modules act as a serial cable replacement.  Bytes going in on one XBee serial port come out on the other's and vice versa.

Comment: So can I use Xbee with RC522 reader then? I'm sorry I don't have knowledge in this area.